# Can you pass a variable with includeJsFile?

Tags: variable, javascript, include

Can you do something similar to using "with" in twig's include tag (http://twig.sensiolabs.org/doc/tags/include.html), but instead with includeJsFile?

I am using a plugin to filter my entries by their tags. The js initiation for this plugin requires me to list all the tags I'm using as a variable. I'd love to assign a variable to the tag group I'm using and pass it to the javascript file, rather than hard code the tag names. Is this possible?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can't pass a JS variable into a JS file (that doesn't quite make sense). What you *can* do is to *create* a JS variable, and make it accessible to the script you are including.

So you'd include your JS file as you are already doing:

```
{% includeJsFile 'path/to/file' %}
```

And then you would create your variable, and **in JavaScript** pass that variable back into the script which you called.

```javascript
{% includejs %}
    var myData = 'whatever your data needs to be';
    functionFromIncludedScript(myData);
{% endincludejs %}
```

The snag you're going to run into here is, **the order matters**. When you use Craft's `include` methods, they will always include any *files* before any *raw scripts*. So using this method, your variable will be defined after the file has already been included.

> It's important to note, the "files before raw scripts" will happen **regardless** of which order you defined them in Twig.

Similarly, be aware that your file include and raw script include will both happen **at the bottom of the page**, just before the closing `</body>` tag.

---

Now I'm going to make an assumption... You're about to say "But I need my variable declared before the file is included!"

Fair enough, and the solution is pretty simple. Just declare your JS variable **in the middle of the page**, while you're rendering the main Twig code:

```html
<script>
    var myData = 'whatever your data needs to be';
</script>
```

So your variable declaration gets rendered along with the rest of your HTML, and your `includeJsFile` still happens at the bottom of the page. By the time that file is included, your JS variable is sitting around waiting for it.

Comment: Thanks for your answer! I can't get anything in a <script> tag to work, though - even just a console.log. Also, am I able to use twig outputs in the <script> tag like {{ craft.tags }}?

Comment: Sounds like a separate question... Would you mind [posting a new question](http://craftcms.stackexchange.com/questions/ask) with some code examples of what you've tried so far?

Comment: Also, if this solution answered your original question, feel free to mark it as "accepted" :)

Comment: Sure, I'll post a new question about the script tags. I think your explanation will work, but since I can't declare the variable in the script tag, I can't verify yet.

Comment: I've posted my new question [here](http://craftcms.stackexchange.com/questions/10949/can-i-set-a-js-variable-to-a-twig-output-tag). I was able to print to the console after a little more debugging, but I still can't get it to accept a twig output.